# Isekai Manhwa/Manhua here mc daughter and wife are murdered

Tags: story-identification, manga, isekai

I wanted to ask something does anyone know a series like *The Live*, where the main character's wife and daughter is murdered and the murderer disappears from the map for having gone to another world?
I don't remember the name but I know some things.

- Everyone of the MC's world ends up forgetting everything about the murder because he got isekai'd.
- MC gets isekai'd remembering everything.
- After some time MC joins some evil murderers' guild recruiting event because he got information that the person who killed his wife and daughter will be there.
- The start and setting are really close to *The Live* and *Memorize*.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F. When and where did you read this?  Do you remember any details of the character art or scenery?  Check out [this question](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/11874/101407) for more suggestions that might help you remember things you can [edit] into your question.